# \n not working in text area

Tags: php, html, textarea

```
<textarea rows="18" cols="80" style="resize:none;">
<?php
    $str = str_replace('<br>', '\n', 'some text<br><br>another line of text');
    echo($str);
?>
</textarea>
```

Output is

```
some text\n\nanother line of text
```

This is the output that i want.

```
some text

another line of text
```

Anyone know wheres the problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Backslashes in single quotes are interpreted literally. You want double quotes:

```
$str = str_replace('<br>', "\n", 'some text<br><br>another line of text');
///                        ^  ^
```

For details about the different ways to write string literals in php, refer to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).